# Rails - how can I get a random sampling from a model limited to RECENT records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I have a social media application with a feed.  For the main site feed and various other sections, I want to grab a chunk of recent Feeditems as a sample, and then display them ordered by date (created_at).

```
Feeditem.find(:all, order: "created_at DESC", limit: 30)
```

Gives me the most recent 30 Feeditems.

```
Feeditem.all.sample(30)
```

Gives me a random sample of 30 Feeditems, but out of all Feeditems (not just recent ones; could be anywhere in time).

How can I get a random sample of 30 records, from say, the past 100 records, or the past 3 days; something along that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`Feeditem.last(100).sample(30)`

Comment: Thanks, very nice.  To ensure they sort in order, I ended up with the following:

Feeditem.last(100).sample(30).sort_by {|s| - s.created_at.to_i}